# Stay on the same page after logout

Tags: users

Is it possible to stay on the same page after logging out from the frontend, assuming that guests can still view that page?

By default, when logging out we are redirected to the homepage or some specific page set with `postLogoutRedirect` config setting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, `postLogoutRedirect` can be set to a function instead of a static value. So for example, in your template you can generate a hidden field in your logout form (or append a querystring parameter to the logout URL) that contains the path of the current page. Then set this in your general.php:

```
'postLogoutRedirect' => function($siteHandle) {
  return Craft::$app->request->getParam('myLogoutPathParameterName', '/');
}
```

This defaults to the homepage (`'/'`) if the parameter is not found.

Comment: Perfect thanks!